# aspose slide to update series colour

Tags: c#, charts, aspose

```
ChartDataCellFactory fact = chart.ChartData.ChartDataCellFactory;
            ChartSeriesEx series = chart.ChartData.Series[0];

       for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
       {

            fact.GetCell(0, 0, 1, "Index");
            series.Values[check].Value = 10;
       }
```

the above is my current code in updating a chart using aspose.slides.. i would like to know how to change the colour of the code series of the code.

Answer (score 1):

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Please try using the following code snippet which sets a particular series fill color.

```
ChartSeriesEx series = chart.ChartData.Series[0];
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillTypeEx.Solid;
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(32, 202, 250);
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 40));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 64));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 50));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 1, 1));
```

However you may consider taking a look over following code snippet as it may help you in understanding the concept of working with different chart entities. But first I would like to share that on X-axis (Category Axis) the category is plotted and series is plotted on Y-axis( Value axis). Can you please elaborate what do you mean by setting min/max values for x-axis and y-axis. The x-axis only contain the category names. Secondly, in my humble opinion, setting min/max values for value axis is also unavailable in PowerPoint. Can you please share the way in the form of snapshot for setting min/max values for the axis in PowerPoint and I will try to implement the same on my end using Aspose.Slides. Please share information in this regard so that I may help you further.

The following code also shows how to plot series values on secondary axis.

```
PresentationEx pres;
pres = new PresentationEx();
SlideEx sld = pres.Slides[0];
ChartEx chart = sld.Shapes.AddChart(ChartTypeEx.ClusteredColumn, 0, 0, 500, 500);
chart.ChartTitle.Text.Text = "Sample Title";
chart.ChartTitle.Text.CenterText = true;
chart.ChartTitle.Height = 20;
chart.HasTitle = false;
chart.HasLegend = false;
chart.ChartData.Series[0].Labels.ShowValue = true;

chart.SecondCategoryAxis.IsVisible = true;

int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;
ChartDataCellFactory fact = chart.ChartData.ChartDataCellFactory;
chart.ChartData.Series.Clear();
chart.ChartData.Categories.Clear();
int s = chart.ChartData.Series.Count;
s = chart.ChartData.Categories.Count;
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "1"), chart.Type);
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 2, "2"), chart.Type);
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 3, "3"), chart.Type);
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 0, "Age"));
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 0, "Gender"));
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 0, "Status"));
chart.ChartData.Categories.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 0, "Nationality"));
chart.GapDepth = 200;
//chart.GapWidth = 50 I need to be able to do something similar to this code

ChartSeriesEx series = chart.ChartData.Series[0];
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillTypeEx.Solid;
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(32, 202, 250);
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 40));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 64));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 50));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 1, 1));
series.PlotOnSecondAxis = true;

series = chart.ChartData.Series[1];
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillTypeEx.Solid;
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 171);
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 2, 4));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 19));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 2, 50));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 2, 25));
series.PlotOnSecondAxis = true;

series = chart.ChartData.Series[2];
series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillTypeEx.Solid;
series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 136, 188);
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 2, 3));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 17));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 2, 0));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 2, 63));

series.PlotOnSecondAxis = true;

chart.GapDepth = 80;//Values in percentage
chart.GapWidth = 250;

pres.Write("D:\\Aspose Data\\Presentation2.pptx");
```